# Does Karate support the COPY HTTP Method or allow for custom HTTP methods?

Tags: karate

I have tried setting **method** to "*copy*", "*mkcol*", "*lock*", "*unlock*", etc and I have yet to find one that does not cause a Karate ERROR:

**org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "copy" is not defined**

Is there a way to use HTTP Methods like COPY, or do we need to request the feature?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate supports variable references after the `method` keyword. So this works, try it:

```
* def copy = 'copy'
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* method copy
```

Actual output: (although this server does not support `COPY`)

```
1 > COPY https://httpbin.org/anything
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/17.0.5)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#method